# How to install pimcore in subdirectory linux mint?

Tags: linux, pimcore

I have just setup Pimcore using command line,

```
composer create-project pimcore/pimcore ./pimcoretest
```

All directory and files are setup using above command.

My path for PIMCORE in linuxMint  is,

```
/var/www/html/pimcoretest/
```

When i am fire request for installation of pimcore,

```
http://127.0.0.1/pimcoretest
```

its redirect to

`http://127.0.0.1/install`

Just throw the error message like,

```
Not Found

The requested URL /install/ was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80
```

Any clue for install pimcore in mint os using subdirectory?

Thanks.

Comment: I've been there and done this with Pimcore 4, it was not pretty and cause a lot of really bad decisions to be made. Avoid at all costs.

Answer (score 3):

Pimcore doesn't support installation in subdirectories. There is also no easy way to achieve that unofficially.

See this site:
https://www.pimcore.org/docs/latest/Getting_Started/Installation.html

> Keep in mind, that Pimcore needs to be installed into the document root of your web server.

I suggest you use a subdomain instead which will work perfectly fine:
pimcoretest.yourdomain.com

Answer (score -1):

I'm kind of late to the party, but it might still help someone..

I am guessing you want to use subdirectory so you can keep multiple projects in `/var/www/html/`.

You could define a sites-available in apache that listens to your desired domain and uses any subdirectory you want.
Something like [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04).

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/test.com
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/test.com/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name test.com www.test.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

Make sure you define that custom domain in your hosts file (so you don't have to work with ip's or ports

```
/etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
. . .

203.0.113.5 example.com www.example.com
203.0.113.5 test.com www.test.com
```

It should be pretty similar with both apache and nginx. More details can be found on google, there should be tons of in-depth examples/tutorials.

Or, [alternatively](https://github.com/dpfaffenbauer/pimcore-docker-compose), use docker to setup a fully functional pimcore without wasting time on setting your apache/nginx. Ready-to-go images can be found on the Docker Hub for any kind of CMS you might need.